# SQLite shared cache

Tags: sqlite

I have a huge (>10GB) sqlite database that is shared among many (up to CPU core count) processes (same executable). This is a specialized application so RAM is not an issue and I want to cache as much of the database in memory. I have found about [`PRAGMA cache_size;`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size) and I am successfully using it but this blows the RAM usage out of proportion as each of many processes has its own private cache.

Now, I found [SQLite Shared-Cache Mode](http://www.sqlite.org/sharedcache.html) but I can't see if this applies to different processes or just threads in one process. I have run some tests which confirm the latter but I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or whether something else needs to be done to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That page explains that "the same cache can be shared across an entire process".

In theory, you could try to configure your OS so that the entire database is held in the file cache.

If the amount of data in individual queries is small, it might be worthwhile to use a client/server database so that the caching needs to be done only in the server process.